# Find child div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my html code look like :-

```
<div id="secone" class="divs row wow bounceInRight animated">
                        <div class="question" align="center"> {{Questions.QuestionLabel}}</div>
                        <div class="question_img" ng-hide="Questions.QuestionImage == 'no_image.jpg'" align="center"><img src="http://api.smartlearner.com/Images/Images/QuestionImages/{{Questions.QuestionImage}}" class="img-responsive"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix"><br /></div>

                        <div class="list-group list_top" data-toggle="items">
                            <ul class="left1 second optionlist" data-value="{{Questions.QuestionID}}" que-id="{{Questions.QuestionID}}">
                                <li ng-repeat="Options in Questions.Options" id="{{Options.IsCorrectOption}}">
                                    <a class="list-group-item"><i class="">&nbsp;</i><input type="checkbox" value="{{Options.QuestionOptionID}}" style="display:none"><img ng-show="Options.OptionText == ''" src="http://api.smartlearner.com/Images/Images/AnswerImages/{{Options.OptionImage}}" style="max-width:15%">{{Options.OptionText}}</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix"><br /></div>
                        <div class="ShowExplaination">
                            <div>
                                <div class="explation_title">Explanation</div>
                                <p class="expla_per">{{Questions.QuestionDescription}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 clearfix"><br /></div>
                    </div>
```

i want to find 'ShowExplaination' class using 'optionlist' class which is inside , pls.help me out...

Comment: where's your jquery code?

Comment: You may use `$('#secone').find('.ShowExplaination');`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal why use one jQuery function when two will do...? ;)

Comment: OP stated: `i want to find 'ShowExplaination' class using 'secone' id`

Comment: can you help me to find out 'ShowExplaination' using 'optionlist' class which is inside <ul> ,i'm getting confused....Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$('#secone .ShowExplanation')` to find that element.

Comment: Alnitak, can you help me to find out 'ShowExplaination' using 'optionlist' class which is inside <ul> ,i'm getting confused....Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help you. i am doing this to find the class for showing you using the each loop.you can eliminate  the loop and use it as you required.

```
 $('div .optionlist').parent().parent().find('.ShowExplaination').each(function (){
              console.log('sf'+$(this).attr('class'));
          })
```